# ¿Como obtener el nombre de una palabra que esta depues de otra con PHP?

Tags: php

En un formulario ingreso un `query` (sentencia sql) dinámico, que después usare para hacer una consulta a multiples conexiones y despues hacer un `insert select`, el problema que tengo es que no se que cual es el nombre de la tabla a la que le voy hacer el insert, de tal modo que mi problema radica en como saco el nombre de la tabla despues del **FROM** del query

Agradeceria el interes.

Comment: La verdad, me parece @JDavid que no esta claro el caso que tienes que plantear. Si es solo el primer from y siempre es una unica tabla, puede que sea facil resolver directamente con expresiones regulares, pero... que pasaria si despues del FROM tienes un INNER JOIN? quizas tendrias que mirar hasta que encuentres un WHERE, pero... y si la consulta tiene subconsulta? cual es la tabla que quieres cojer (de que FROM) o si no tienes where y tienes ORDER BY o GROUP BY?

Comment: @Jakala, es muy valido tu comentario, tendria que reeplantear el requerimiento, pues no habia caido en cuenta que pasa si puede tener una subconsulta o lo demas que mencionas, muchas gracias por el comentario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para hacer eso puedes usar "strstr()" para buscas la palara "from" y todo lo que este despues.

Luego le puedes hacer un explode para dividir la cadena por espacios y la palabra que le sigue será el nombre de la tabla.

```
echo $sql='SELECT * from mytabla where cosas';
echo '<br>';
echo explode(' ',strstr($sql, 'from'))[1];
```

Esto de dará como resultado:

```
SELECT * from mytabla where cosas
mytabla
```

Comment: es una respuesta excelente, muchas gracias por tu colaboración

Comment: @JDavid de nada (ノ・∀・)ノ

Answer (score 0):

Una de las formas que se me ocurrió hacer, fue convertir el `query(que es un string)` en un `array` y sacar la posición de **FROM** para obtener el nombre de la tabla, pues siempre va a estar después del **FROM**

```
$cadena = "SELECT * FROM tb_users";
$array = explode(" ", $cadena);

$position = null;
foreach($array as $key => $data){
    if($data == "FROM" || $data == "from"){
        $position = $key;
    }
}

print_r($array[$position+1]);
```

Pero si es hay una solución mucho mas corta, es una gran ayuda.